# Link Android SDK tools to Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova, android-sdk-tools

I have been using the android standalone SDK. Now I want to use it with Visual Studio Community.

I installed VScommunity but it goes ahead to download the entire SDK again which I do not want.

Is there a way I can link to it so the emulator and adb tools can be used by visual studio.

-Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way I can link to it so the emulator and adb tools can be used by visual studio.

By default VS installs the third party dependencies for you to run the tool. You can clear the checkbox of any component that you don't want to install in the **Common Tools and Software Development Kits** group of the Visual Studio installer.

[image]

VS detects the third party configuration of your Android SDK. And you can check or override them under Tools Menu->Options->Tools for Apache Cordova->Environment Variables Overrides.

For details about installing third party dependencies manually, you can refer to [this document](http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/configure-vs-tools-apache-cordova/#ThirdParty).